# Cisco replacement - configuration compatibility

Tags: cisco

We have several Cisco Switch (3650), these switch are End Of Life and we want to replace them.

A vendor propose us to replace them by Cisco 9300.

Will we be able to just upload the configuration of the 3650 on the new 9300 ?

Or do we need to change the configuration in order to make it compliant with the new model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, the configuration should be the same. There may be some incompatibilities, depending on the specific features you use, and the specific software versions. You can check the release notes of the IOS version you are moving to to see what features are different.